# Active launcher icons glow when using numix theme

Tags: 14.04, gtk3

I'm running unity with numix gtk theme.

When switching between the launcher apps using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the launcher icons glow to show the current active app is missing. I don't know if this is because the launcher 'tiles' are hidden by default.

How can I get the glow back?